# Why I got zero if I add `delete[] d;` in the following code snippet?

Tags: c++

Why I got zero if I add `delete[] d;` in the following code snippet? Here is the link I run on ideone.com: https://ideone.com/WxbaJt

If I remove the `delete[] d;` then the answer is correct(544320). But I want to reset the array in each cycle of `i`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    int sum=0;
    int init=10000000;
    int end=99999999;
    int *d=0;

    for (int i=init; i<=end; i++) {
        int j=i;
        d = new int[10];
        while (j>0) {
            d[j%10]++;
            j/=10;
        }
        bool repeat = false;
        for (int k=0;k<=9;k++) {
            if (d[k]>=2) {
                repeat=true;
            }
        }
        if (!repeat) {
            if (i%3==0)
                sum++;
        }
        delete[] d;
    }

    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your output  is unpredictable, because elements of `d` array are not initialized, call `d = new int[10]();` to initialize all items to 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you allocate memory with `new[]` it will be *uninitialized*, the contents of the memory will be *indeterminate* and using it in any way except to initialize it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead of using dynamically allocated memory that you must remember to free at the end of each iteration, I suggest you use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

You can create it with a specific number of elements, each initialized to a specific value. For example

```
std::vector<int> d(10);  // Create 10 default-initilized (zero) integers
```

When the loop iterates, the vector goes out of scope and its lifetime ends. And when the loop start over in the next iteration, a new a fresh vector will be created.

Comment: minor addendum: because the same amount of memory is constantly allocated and deallocated, there's a good chance the same memory is assigned to d. This has the sideeffect that the content of the array is the same after the allocation as it was before deallocation.

Comment: and I think, in this case compiler behaves like "post-modern" and when `delete[] d;` present, it evaluates this loop to "nothing has been done". Without `delete` it couldn't optimize out what appeared to be a memory leak. UB is allowed to cause such "optimizations".

Comment: I would prefer `std::array<int, 10> d {0};` or `int d[10] = {0};`. The array has always the size 10.